# JS passing the forEach variable to the lookup function

Tags: javascript, tabulator

Please help me understand how I can pass this argument to the lookup function of the `formatter`. I try to dynamically create table rows for tabulator:

**works**:

```
keys = ["name", "price", "number"];
doAjax().then( variable => { 
    if ( products ) {
        let cols = [{title: "number", field: "number"}];
        keys.forEach(function ( key ) {
            let formatter = "";

            // check if key is number
            if ( key == "number" ) {
                formatter = function( cell ) {
                                return `<div íd="${key}">${cell.getValue()}</div>`;
                            };
            };
            cols.push({title: key, field: "data." + key, formatter: formatter});
         });
    };
 });
```

**does not work**:

```
let testf = function( cell, key ) { 
    return `<div íd="${key}">${cell.getValue()}</div>`; // key is not accessible here
};

keys = ["name", "price", "number"];
doAjax().then( variable => { 
    if ( products !== null ) {
        let cols = [{title: "number", field: "number"}];
        keys.forEach(function ( key ) {
            let formatter = "";

            // check if key is number
            if ( key == "number" ) {
                formatter = testf(cell, key);  // not working
            };
            cols.push({title: key, field: "data." + key, formatter: formatter});
         });
    };
 });
```

**code for context**:

```
var table = new Tabulator("#products", {
    ajaxURL: "api/products",
    columns: cols,
});
```

How could I rewrite the second approach, so it gets the argument key passed along?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a function that takes the initial `cell` as an argument, and calls `testf` with it and the `key`.

```
if (key == "number") {
    formatter = cell => testf(cell, key);
};
```

Comment: this is the short version of what I had written in my **works** approach, right? Kind of exactlty the same, just different notation? Can you elaborate (it works, I just want to understand more).

Comment: `formatter` needs to be a function that accepts `cell` as a parameter, and returns an HTML string. It only accepts that one `cell` parameter - it doesn't know anything about `key`, so `key` needs to be defined in the outer scope instead. So, inside the handler, `testf(cell, key)` will be able to call the function with the cell (from the argument) and the key (from the outer scope).

Answer (score 0):

Just make key the first argument, and bind it:

```
let testf = function( key, cell ) { 
    return `<div íd="${key}">${cell.getValue()}</div>`; 
}

formatter = testf.bind(key);
```

Comment: I had to switch `let testf = function( key, cell )` to `let testf = function( cell, key )`. Now `cell` is correct, but key is empty? tried: `formatter = testf.bind(key);` and `let testf = function( key, cell ) { console.log( key, '|', cell ) };` and I get in the console: `{} | [object Object] //correct`